# How many windows of N length can fit on a discontinuous array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

Given an arbitrary array where all values are 1 or 0, how many (edit: what is the maximum number of) non-overlapping windows of length N can fit on the array? A window must be centered on 1 (True) value. (edit: assume N is odd). The sides of the window can be 0s and values on the ends of the array can count as valid.  I'd prefer answers using numpy and/or pandas if possible.

Real-world use-case would be something like scheduling meetings such that they don't overlap.  The array could represent days of the year, with a 1 being a day available to hold a meeting, and a rule that meetings must be scheduled with at least 2 days between.

example:

```
array_1 = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]

array_2 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]



count_windows(array=array_1, window_size=3)
```

out: 3
explanation:
windows by indices: `[0, 1],  [2, 3, 4],  [6, 7, 8]`

```
count_windows(array=array_2, window_size=3)
```

out: 1
explanation:
windows by indices: `[2, 3, 4]`  A window centered on index 5 would include index 4, which would be an overlap with the window centered on index 3

Comment: What are the windows in the first example?

Comment: @mozway explanation added.  I may not be using the best terminology

Comment: Thanks, that's more clear with the corrected example ;) What if you have several possibilities? Do you want the max number (non trivial) or the first available windows?

Comment: Are the windows always odd in length so that there is a defined center?

Comment: @mozway max number, ideally.

Comment: Why is [0,1] a valid subwindow if the window size is 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am wrong, the greedy algorithm is optimal in such case.

That is, you consider the first available 1 of your array, and you make a window centered on it, without consideration for the consequences (what window it will prevent). And proceed then with next possible 1 (that is next one that is at least `window_size` further.

Greedy algorithms are fast, because they are always linear (never go back on a decision). But sometimes they are optimal. And here, I think it is.
Because, what could be the consequence of not using the first possible 1 of the array?
Only that it may prevent a window on some other 1, within than window. But only 1 window at most is prevented. Even if there were two 1 in that window, there are too close to each other so that you could have used them both.
So, worst case scenario, with "using the 1st one", is that it blocks 1 other window. But since it brings a window, it is 1 vs 1. So, worst case scenario, it is a neutral operation. Best case scenario, it is beneficial. So, no reason not to take the first one.

So, greedy algorithm is optimal

```py
def count_windows5(arr,sz):
    i=0
    n=0
    while i<len(arr):
        if arr[i]:
            n+=1
            i+=sz
        else:
            i+=1
    return n
```

## Branch and bound approach.

Since I came here pretty certain that it was a NP-hard problem, since it looks like a classical chromatic number problem. In a graph where you have all "1" as vertices, and edge between "1" that are less than `window_size` apart, the answer to your question is the number of "1" minus the chromatic number of the graph.
So it doesn't just look like a chromatic number problem. It is a chromatic number problem. Solving the chromatic number answer to your question. And answering to your question answer to the chromatic number problem.

And chromatic number problems are NP-hard. Well, they usually are. But there are subclasses of problem in which they are not. And it happens to be one.
In your case, the problem can be solved in O(n), using previously given greedy algorithm.

But since before I understood that, I wrote an answer using branch&bound, let's post it anyway

For such an exponential problem, roughly, what you do is just explore all combination, exclude impossible ones, and count the number of windows in possibles one. Here the number of combinations is 2ᵏ where k is the number of 1. Because for each 1, you can either use it, or not.

We can explore that recursively (that is the step 0 of branch&bound: branch&bound is just brute-force exploration of all possible solutions; but that exploration is made in the form of an implicit decision tree — often implemented by a recursive  algorithm, in which with optimizations, you can exclude whole branches without even exploring them)

Here is version 0, that just explore all combinations (almost all: we don't try 1 that are already excluded at a given stage)

```py
def count_windows1(arr, sz):
    if len(arr)==0: return 0 # No room for a window

    first1=np.argmax(arr)
    if arr[first1]==0: return 0 # no possible window in this all 0 array

    # So we have a 1 here. No we have 2 choices (and then in both other "subchoices"
    # but that is the job of the recursive calls).
    # Either we use it, or we don't. 

    # Case 0: we don't. So same as count_windows without this 1.
    case0 = count_windows1(arr[first1+1:], sz)


    # Case 1: we do. So same as 1 + count_windows without this 1, and without 
    # the next sz//2 numbers that are the  right tail of this window
    # and without sz//2 other numbers, that can't be next center, since
    # there must be room for the left tail of the next window
    # So, since 1+sz//2+sz//2 = sz, sz being odd, ...
    case1 = 1+count_windows1(arr[first1+sz:], sz)

    # max is the best
    return max(case0, case1)
```

But sometimes that "should I use it or not" question can be solved without interaction with other 1: a 1 surrounded by 0 (up to `window_size`) can be taking without even thinking about it, since it can't prevent to take another one.

Hence a second version (still not really a branch&bound, tho we already cut some whole branches of the decision tree)

```py
def count_windows2(arr, sz):
    if len(arr)==0: return 0 # No room for a window

    first1=np.argmax(arr)
    if arr[first1]==0: return 0 # no possible window in this all 0 array

    # So we have a 1 here. No we have 2 choices (and then in both other "subchoices"
    # but that is the job of the recursive calls).
    # Either we use it, or we don't. 

    # Case 1: we do. So same as 1 + count_windows without this 1, and without 
    # the next sz//2 numbers that are the  right tail of this window
    # and without sz//2 other numbers, that can't be next center, since
    # there must be room for the left tail of the next window
    # So, since 1+sz//2+sz//2 = sz, sz being odd, ...
    case1 = 1+count_windows2(arr[first1+sz:], sz)

    # Case 0: we don't. So same as count_windows without this 1.
    if arr[first1+1:first1+1+sz//2].any():
        case0 = count_windows2(arr[first1+1:], sz)
        return max(case0, case1)
    else:
        # No need to even try case0: why on earth wouldn't we take this 1, when it prevents no other potential window?
        # (other than previous ones, but that has been handled in caller)
        return case1
```

(and you see that this is that reasoning which, when extended, lead to greedy algorithm at the end: even 1 that interact with others, if it is the first 1, has no reason not to be used)

To make it a proper branch&bound, we add a `target` parameter, saying what score we need to reach for the answer to be interesting (for the first call, it is obviously 0. But if, taking a 1, you reach a score of 3, then not taking it is interesting only if you can have 4 without it. Which can occur obviously only if there are 4 remaining "1").

```py
# target=best solution seen so far for this array
def count_windows3(arr, sz, target=0):
    if len(arr)==0: return 0 # No room for a window
    if arr.sum()<=target: return 0 # Why even bother: we have no chance to do better than the target

    first1=np.argmax(arr)
    if arr[first1]==0: return 0 # no possible window in this all 0 array

    # So we have a 1 here. No we have 2 choices (and then in both other "subchoices"
    # but that is the job of the recursive calls).
    # Either we use it, or we don't. 

    # Case 1: we do. So same as 1 + count_windows without this 1, and without 
    # the next sz//2 numbers that are the  right tail of this window
    # and without sz//2 other numbers, that can't be next center, since
    # there must be room for the left tail of the next window
    # So, since 1+sz//2+sz//2 = sz, sz being odd, ...
    case1 = 1+count_windows3(arr[first1+sz:], sz)

    # Case 0: we don't. So same as count_windows without this 1.
    if arr[first1+1:first1+1+sz//2].any():
        case0 = count_windows3(arr[first1+1:], sz, case1)
        return max(case0, case1)
    else:
        # No need to even try case0: why on earth wouldn't we take this 1, when it prevents no other potential window?
        # (other than previous ones, but that has been handled in caller)
        return case1
```

And it is when trying to build an example that shows that, that is an example where not taking a "1" can allow better score that taking it, that I realized that there wasn't any such example, for reason already given.

So, in reality, our criterium to decide when to call recursively `case0` (which, so far is `iff that 1 is interacting with at least another 1, and if without it, there are at least case1+1 1 remaining, otherwise, it can't be better), becomes much simpler: it is "never". There aren't any cases where` case0`could be better than`case1`.

Hence the last version of the "branch&bound"

```py
# Greedy algorithm. Case0 is never optimal anyway. Just use always case1
def count_windows4(arr, sz):
    if len(arr)==0: return 0 # No room for a window

    first1=np.argmax(arr)
    if arr[first1]==0: return 0 # no possible window in this all 0 array

    case1 = 1+count_windows4(arr[first1+sz:], sz)
    return case1
```

Except that this is no longer branch and bound. There is no tree here, since we have only one branch. This is just, now that we cut inconditionally the `case0` branch, this is just a recursive implementation of the greedy algorithm. Which I translated into an iterative algorithm that I've already shown at the top of this answer.

Comment: And thank you for the thoroughness and background of your answer.  I'm frustrated that I wasn't even sure how to ask it properly.  You've given me a lot of good options for continuing to learn, though.

Answer (score 2):

### Improved solution

After reading [@chrslg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20037042/chrslg)'s solution, I realized how I could rewrite my original answer (included below for posterity) using a single `for` loop rather than the original nested loop. This solution still makes use of `np.where` to find the locations of the 1s, but the change comes from looping through each of those indices and adding them to the window centers if it is at least the `window_size` distance away from the previous window center. My code continues to use the greedy algorithm.

I had also misunderstood that the desired output was just the number of windows and not the windows themselves, so I included an option to also return the windows if that is of interest. (The method involves adding and subtracting from the center index to get the window extents and then dropping the negative indices, which happens if a 1 is at or near the beginning or end.)

```py
import numpy as np

def count_windows(arr, window_size, return_windows=False):
    assert window_size % 2, "window_size is not odd."
    
    a = np.where(arr)[0]
    centers = [a[0]]
    for _a in a[1:]:
        if _a - centers[-1] >= window_size:
            centers.append(_a)
    n_windows = len(centers)
    
    if return_windows:
        n = (window_size - 1)//2
        b = np.stack(np.array(centers)+np.arange(-n, n+1)[:,None], axis=1)
        return n_windows, [row[row >= 0].tolist() for row in b]
    
    return n_windows
    

array_1 = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
array_2 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]

print(count_windows(array_1, 3))        # 3
print(count_windows(array_1, 3, True))  # (3, [[0, 1], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]])
print(count_windows(array_2, 3))        # 1
print(count_windows(array_2, 3, True))  # (1, [[2, 3, 4]])
```

---

I have a solution that is most likely non-optimal (i.e. it doesn't maximize the number of windows, rather it chooses the first valid windows). It also has a nested `for` loop, so this solution will be slow for large arrays. Maybe someone can use this answer to find a vectorized solution.

Essentially, my solution finds the indices where the value is 1 (using `np.where`) and then creates a window of indices around each of those points (I'm assuming `window_size` is always odd). It then checks for overlaps between each window (using `np.isin`) and keeps the window if there is no overlap. Finally, it removes any possible duplicate rows it may have added to the resulting list (using `np.unique`) and gets rid of negative numbers (negative indices happen when a 1 is close to the beginning or end). The return value is a python.

```py
import numpy as np

def count_windows(arr, window_size):
    assert window_size % 2, "window_size is not odd."
    
    a = np.where(arr)[0]
    n = (window_size - 1)//2
    b = np.stack(a+np.arange(-n, n+1)[:,None], axis=1)
    windows = [b[0]]
    for i in range(b.shape[0]):
        for j in range(i+1, b.shape[0]):
            if ~np.isin(b[i], b[j]).any():
                windows.append(b[j])
                
    c = np.unique(windows, axis=0)
    return [row[row >= 0].tolist() for row in c]
    

array_1 = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
array_2 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]

print(count_windows(array_1, 3))  # [[0, 1], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
print(count_windows(array_2, 3))  # [[2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: So that is (by your description: chooses the first valid window), another implementation of the greedy algorithm. If so, then (see beginning of my answer) it *is* optimal (I mean, it gives the optimal answer. Not sure it gives it in optimal time, since it looks quite complex compared to my greedy algorithm, but on the other hand, you solve a more complex problem: returning the windows, not just the count). Not that greedy (taking first possible case) are in general. But it happens to be a problem where you can prove that none of the (numerous) other combinations would be better.

Comment: @chrslg Yes, my algorithm is a greedy algorithm. But for some reason I didn't see it how you explained it, so I ended up with a naive O(n^2) (well, n is the number of 1s). If I get a chance, I'll update my answer to include a linear version, though I didn't understand at first that OP wanted the number of windows not the windows themselves.

Comment: @chrslg I updated my answer to include a solution that only uses a single (explicit) `for` loop for finding the window centers.

Comment: Your answer returning the windows could be useful, and I appreciate your example.  I accepted @chrslg's answer for the inclusion of the theoretical background, and for providing the context of the problem (i.e. how the question relates to other problems)